# JSON data to plotly

Tags: javascript, json, plotly

I am stuck with syntax and need some help, I have simple data set that I need to plot out as timeline with 2 filled lines (Time Series with Rangeslider).

My data set format is:

```html
[{"pm10": 12.1, "pm25": 7.0, "time": "13.08.2018 12:25:09"}, {"pm25": 6.6, "pm10": 11.1, "time": "13.08.2018 12:30:49"}, {"pm10": 12.6, "pm25": 6.2, "time": "13.08.2018 16:59:06"},   {"pm10": 9.2, "pm25": 5.8, "time": "13.08.2018 19:37:01"}, {"pm25": 5.1, "pm10": 8.7, "time": "13.08.2018 19:42:46"},   {"pm10": 7.3, "pm25": 5.5, "time": "13.08.2018 21:42:23"}, {"pm25": 5.1, "pm10": 7.1, "time": "13.08.2018 21:47:56"}, {"pm10": 8.3, "pm25": 5.5, "time": "13.08.2018 21:53:28"}]
```

I have done everything to make the JSON in this format, so I cant figure out how to:

- grab live data (on load) from external .JSON file
- format the array in a way that plotly can display 2 lines (pm25 and pm10)

I have spend 3 days on this already, any help appreciated.

i tried the samples from other answers and gotten so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/v15wmeuL/2/

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: We're happy to help you, but your question is too vague for anybody being able to do so. We have no code, no context, no information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To grab data from external JSON, look at xmlHttpRequests or an equivalent.

I made some adaptations to your code that displays the data you wanted as two curves:

```
let trace1 = {
  x: [],
  y: [],
  mode: "lines"
};
let trace2 = {
  x: [],
  y: [],
  mode: "lines"
};
data.forEach(function(val) {
  trace1.x.push(val["time"]);
  trace1.y.push(val["pm25"]);
  trace2.x.push(val["time"]);
  trace2.y.push(val["pm10"]);
});
Plotly.newPlot('AQI', [trace1, trace2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery, then below syntax would be helpful:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'GET',
async: false,
url: '/api-data',
success: function (data) {
    let trace1 = {
        x: [],
        y: [],
        mode: "lines"
    };
    let trace2 = {
        x: [],
        y: [],
        mode: "lines"
    };
    data.forEach(function(val) {
        trace1.x.push(val["time"]);
        trace1.y.push(val["pm25"]);
        trace2.x.push(val["time"]);
        trace2.y.push(val["pm10"]);
    });
    Plotly.newPlot('AQI', [trace1, trace2]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Awsome, the the plotting part works!

But I still cant get the data retrieval part fails.

This is what i have so far:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     }
};

 data = xmlhttp.open("GET", 
 "http://192.168.0.170/aqi.json", true);

let trace1 = {
  x: [],
  y: [],
  mode: "lines"
  };
let trace2 = {
  x: [],
  y: [],
  mode: "lines"
  };
data.forEach(function(val) {
 trace1.x.push(val["time"]);
 trace1.y.push(val["pm25"]);
 trace2.x.push(val["time"]);
 trace2.y.push(val["pm10"]);
});
Plotly.newPlot('AQI', [trace1, trace2]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v15wmeuL/14/ for the plotting part. - also plotly requires specific date format - so had to amend incoming data.

Comment: you need to call the send() method on your request object and you need an onload event handler on it, too. You deal with the data in the context of that event handler. I suggest you look at the documentation at mdn. Also, I guess posting a follow up question as an answer isn't really good practice.